# db2cmd SQL Output Vertically

Tags: sql, db2

How to show the SQL table in vertically?

```
db2 => SELECT * FROM a
```

===== Row #1 =====

```
X: 1
Y: apple
Z: 10
```

===== Row #2 =====

```
X: 10
Y: kiwi
Z: 20
```

Normally is like this

```
db2 => SELECT * FROM a
X     Y      Z 
--- ------- -----
1   apple   10 
10  kiwi    20
```

Comment: X: 1   Y: apple   Z: 10 IS SINGLE ROW you want or seperate for X , Y Z ?

Comment: yes in single row XYZ is in 3 column

Comment: search for pivot

Comment: cmd can search for pivot, how ?

Comment: still no get the answer :(

Comment: To clarify: I think OP is asking for something like PostgreSQL's `\x` expanded view.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
SELECT A FROM
(
SELECT X,concat('X:',X)A FROM #Table 
union
SELECT X,concat('Y:',Y) FROM #Table  
union
SELECT X,concat('Z:',Z) FROM #Table  
)a
```

[Check Demo](http://rextester.com/CCDA42130)

> OutPut

[image]

Comment: the XYZ is the column name, I don't want join data, example like:
X (is column name): 1 (is row data)
I display in cmd